# Cannot assign value to type 'String' to type 'CAMediaTimingFillMode'

Tags: swift, string

Keep getting an issue where it says "Cannot Assign Value to type 'string' to type 'CAMEdiaTimingFillMode' undergroup.fillmode= MotionanimationFillModeToValue(Mode: .both)

Suggested fix from XCode Replace 'group.fillMode = MotionAnimationFillModeToValue(mode: .both)' with 'CAMediaTimingFillMode(rawValue: group.fillMode = MotionAnimationFillModeToValue(mode: .both)) ?? <#default value#>' which just creates a loop.

```
    public class func animate(group animations: [CAAnimation], timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction = .easeInOut, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.5) -> CAAnimationGroup {
        let group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.fillMode = MotionAnimationFillModeToValue(mode: .both)
        group.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        group.animations = animations
        group.duration = duration
        group.timingFunction = timingFunction
        return group
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `fillMode` is `CAMediaTimingFillMode`, an enum, and the `timingFunction` parameter must be a `CAMediaTimingFunction` instance

```
public class func animate(group animations: [CAAnimation],
                    timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction = .init(name: .easeInEaseOut),
                    duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.5) -> CAAnimationGroup {
    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.fillMode = .both
    group.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    group.animations = animations
    group.duration = duration
    group.timingFunction = timingFunction
    return group
}
```